# Django: running queries on resulting union query

Tags: python, mysql, django, group-by, union

Is there a way of writing this raw query using Django's ORM? I am trying to avoid using a raw query, because I would like to run additional filters on the resulting query.

I will show what I am currently doing which is probably wrong, but the end result of what I want is to have an inbox that first shows entries where some new action occurred at the top and then list all other entries based on their submit date.

```
SELECT result.id,
max(result.submit_date) submit_date, 
FROM (
  (SELECT
  table_A.submit_date,
  table_A.id,
  FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B ON
  (table_A.domain_id = table_B.id) WHERE 
  (table_B.company_id = 3 AND table_A.deleted = FALSE))  

  UNION

  (SELECT
  (time) AS submit_date,
  (table_C.table_A_id) AS id,
  FROM table_C INNER JOIN table_A ON 
  (table_C.table_A_id = table_A.id) WHERE
  (table_C.verb_type IN (8, 9, 14) AND 
  table_C.company_id = 3 AND table_A.deleted = FALSE) )
) result

GROUP BY result.id ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

UPDATE:
Here are my models:

```
#inbox entries
class table_A(models.Model):
  domain = models.ForeignKey(table_B)
  submit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


#domain entries
class table_B(models.Model):
  company = models.ForeignKey(table_D)
  domain = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


#action entries associated with table_A (inbox entries)
class table_C(models.Model):
  GAMMA = 0
  OMEGA = 1
  PHI = 8
  CHI = 9
  SIGMA = 14
  VERB_CHOICE = (
    (GAMMA, 'action gamma'),
    (OMEGA, 'action omega'),
    (PHI, 'action phi'),
    (CHI, 'action chi'),
    (SIGMA, 'action sigma'),
  )
  company = models.ForeignKey(table_D)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  ref_t_A = models.ForeignKey(table_A)
  verb_type = models.SmallIntegerField(
    choices=VERB_CHOICES,
    default=GAMMA,
    db_index=True
  )
  time = models.DateTimeField(
    verbose_name='date of entry creation',
    auto_now_add=True,
    db_index=True
  )

 # company entries
 class table_D(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   create_date = models.DateTimeField(
     verbose_name='date account created',
     auto_now_add=True
   )
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

So far, I can create a union between table_A (inbox entries) and table_C (actions on entries) using the Django ORM, but then I would like to perform the outer select or some other method of doing this completely so the end result is sorted the way I need it to be, with the newly modified entries being listed at the top based on their action date and the rest of the entries listed below based on their submit date (since they do not have an action associated with them yet):

```
x = table_A.values_list( 'submit_date', 'id',)
y = table_C.objects.filter(
  company_id=2,
  verb_type__in=[
    table_C.PHI,
    table_C.CHI,
    table_C.SIGMA
  ]
  ref_t_A__deleted=False
).extra(
  select={
    'id': 'ref_t_A_id',
    'submit_date': 'time',
  }
).values_list('id', 'submit_date',)

z = x.union(y)
```

The aim of the raw query was to order entries in table_A by latest action associated with it from table_C, and use the submit_date if there is no action associated with it from table_C. Once I get the latest action or submit_date associated with the entries in table_A, I would like to then order the results based on the date of the latest action or submit_date.

**I would like to run filters on z, and any other operation I would as if it were a queryset from the model of table_A.**

Comment: please, show you models and add information what result do you want.

Comment: Ok @Bear Brown, I updated everything, I absolute appreciate any insight you can provide to help me solve this, if you have ay further info please do not hesitate to ask, thank you again.